# Store shared pointer in lambda to keep it alive

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, shared-ptr, functor

A struct like this is intended to be stored in a lambda:

```
struct MyStruct {
  void testfunction() {
    // Do something
  }
};
```

What I want is to construct a shared pointer from that and store this pointer in a lambda:

```
auto ptr = std::make_shared<MyStruct>();
std::function<void()> caller = [ptr](){
  ptr->testFunction();
}
```

The caller object is given to a function and is copied by that function. The `ptr` object goes out of scope. Is the shared pointer still alive when I  pass the caller object around?

Is it guaranteed that `ptr` is stored in the lambda and the object is managed by that pointer as long as caller exists or was returned? Are there any compiler optimizations if I do not call `testFunction`?

This problem is specific to a `boost::asio` problem where I want to pass some object withing an asynchronous handler.

Comment: Yes, it will be alive (you can check that by adding logging to ctors/dtor). Since there is no UB involved, the optimizer won't break this code.

Comment: What HolyBlackCat said. The lambda captures a copy of `ptr` and uses it. No optimizer can mess with that. Not without being a buggy optimizer anyway.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat +1. Its `reference_count` is also taken care of, *as expected*?

Comment: You mean `use_count()`? Yes, why wouldn't it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

> If the lambda-expression captures anything by copy (either implicitly with capture clause `[=]` or explicitly with a capture that does not include the character &, e.g. `[a, b, c]`), the closure type includes unnamed non-static data members, declared in unspecified order, that hold copies of all entities that were so captured.

So, in accordance with [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), it is expected that your compiler will generate code which will behave like if you really have this copy and so object will be kept alive.